# How to fix "Failed to apply 'Node' resource: [update conflict: Node(...)]" while trying to apply Calico node config?

Tags: networking, kubernetes, calico

I'm playing with Kubernetes and got two VirtualBox machines - master and worker. Every one has two network interfaces - one for Internet and other for communication between each other VM and host machine. And I got troubles with Calico setup because it autodetects wrong network interface. I've made few settings to fix it but one trouble remains - worker takes wrong IP. And I found how to fix it - but it does not work. Details below.

Current worker config is (`10.0.3.15` is those "wrong" IP):

```
[12:35]user@ubuntu-vbox-k8s-master[~]$ ./calicoctl get node ubuntu-vbox-k8s-worker -o yaml
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: Node
metadata:
  annotations:
    projectcalico.org/kube-labels: '{"beta.kubernetes.io/arch":"amd64","beta.kubernetes.io/os":"linux","kubernetes.io/arch":"amd64","kubernetes.io/hostname":"ubuntu-vbox-k8s-worker","kubernetes.io/os":"linux"}'
  creationTimestamp: "2021-09-26T10:59:00Z"
  labels:
    beta.kubernetes.io/arch: amd64
    beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
    kubernetes.io/arch: amd64
    kubernetes.io/hostname: ubuntu-vbox-k8s-worker
    kubernetes.io/os: linux
  name: ubuntu-vbox-k8s-worker
  resourceVersion: "9219"
  uid: 6f5efd41-e06c-4f9d-9b3a-248af88a385e
spec:
  addresses:
  - address: 10.0.3.15/24
    type: CalicoNodeIP
  - address: 10.0.3.15
    type: InternalIP
  bgp:
    ipv4Address: 10.0.3.15/24
    ipv4IPIPTunnelAddr: 192.168.77.64
  orchRefs:
  - nodeName: ubuntu-vbox-k8s-worker
    orchestrator: k8s
status: {}
```

I try to apply fixed one:

```
[12:37]user@ubuntu-vbox-k8s-master[~]$ cat calico-worker.yaml 
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: Node
metadata:
  annotations:
    projectcalico.org/kube-labels: '{"beta.kubernetes.io/arch":"amd64","beta.kubernetes.io/os":"linux","kubernetes.io/arch":"amd64","kubernetes.io/hostname":"ubuntu-vbox-k8s-worker","kubernetes.io/os":"linux"}'
  creationTimestamp: "2021-09-26T10:59:00Z"
  labels:
    beta.kubernetes.io/arch: amd64
    beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
    kubernetes.io/arch: amd64
    kubernetes.io/hostname: ubuntu-vbox-k8s-worker
    kubernetes.io/os: linux
  name: ubuntu-vbox-k8s-worker
  resourceVersion: "5303"
  uid: 6f5efd41-e06c-4f9d-9b3a-248af88a385e
spec:
  addresses:
  - address: 192.168.56.109
    type: InternalIP
  orchRefs:
  - nodeName: ubuntu-vbox-k8s-worker
    orchestrator: k8s
status: {}
```

and got error:

```
[12:38]user@ubuntu-vbox-k8s-master[~]$ ./calicoctl apply -f calico-worker.yaml 
Failed to apply 'Node' resource: [update conflict: Node(ubuntu-vbox-k8s-worker)]
```

It is strange because I succeeded to fix Calico master node in same way without conflict with config:

```
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: Node
metadata:
  annotations:
    projectcalico.org/kube-labels: '{"beta.kubernetes.io/arch":"amd64","beta.kubernetes.io/os":"linux","kubernetes.io/arch":"amd64","kubernetes.io/hostname":"ubuntu-vbox-k8s-master","kubernetes.io/os":"linux","node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane":"","node-role.kubernetes.io/master":"","node.kubernetes.io/exclude-from-external-load-balancers":""}'
  creationTimestamp: "2021-09-26T10:56:24Z"
  labels:
    beta.kubernetes.io/arch: amd64
    beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
    kubernetes.io/arch: amd64
    kubernetes.io/hostname: ubuntu-vbox-k8s-master
    kubernetes.io/os: linux
    node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane: ""
    node-role.kubernetes.io/master: ""
    node.kubernetes.io/exclude-from-external-load-balancers: ""
  name: ubuntu-vbox-k8s-master
  resourceVersion: "9052"
  uid: 9e6d55c6-f449-4ded-ab47-ea9d889d6b43
spec:
  addresses:
  - address: 192.168.56.108
    type: InternalIP
  bgp:
    ipv4IPIPTunnelAddr: 192.168.77.0
  orchRefs:
  - nodeName: ubuntu-vbox-k8s-master
    orchestrator: k8s
status:
  podCIDRs:
  - 192.168.77.0/24
```

Comment: Well I understand you want to change the yaml and give the calicoctl apply again? Did you try to run `calicoctl replace` command? [Ref](https://docs.projectcalico.org/reference/calicoctl/replace)?

Comment: Hello @DmitriyVinokurov. Any updates?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak, sorry for late reply, was on vacation, now both apply and replace works but nothing changes :(

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor, see above

Comment: Solved, added answer

Answer (score 1):

Solved with help from Calico Slack channel by command `kubectl set env daemonset/calico-node -n kube-system IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD=interface=enp0s3` from https://docs.projectcalico.org/networking/ip-autodetection

Comment: Just used this command for fixing a Calico deploy that was connecting to the wrong subnet and for the life of me was confused how to roll out the change. Here's the command if you don't know the interface but do know the subnet (e.g. `10.141.0.0/24`):  `kubectl -n calico-system set env ds calico-node IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD=cidr=10.141.0.0/24`